# Clip polygon and retain data?

Tags: r, polygon, vector, clip, intersection

I have these two polygons:

```
library(sp); library(rgeos); library(maptools)

coords1 <- matrix(c(-1.841960, -1.823464, -1.838623, -1.841960, 55.663696,
                    55.659178, 55.650841, 55.663696), ncol=2)
coords2 <- matrix(c(-1.822606, -1.816790, -1.832712, -1.822606, 55.657887,
                    55.646806, 55.650679, 55.657887), ncol=2)
p1 <- Polygon(coords1)
p2 <- Polygon(coords2)
p1 <- Polygons(list(p1), ID = "p1")
p2 <- Polygons(list(p2), ID = "p2")
myPolys <- SpatialPolygons(list(p1, p2))
spdf1 = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(myPolys, data.frame(variable1 = c(232,
                                                                   242), variable2 = c(235, 464), row.names = c("p1", "p2")))
proj4string(spdf1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84
+towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(spdf1, col="red")

coords1a <- matrix(c(-1.830219, -1.833753, -1.821154, -1.830219, 55.647353,
                     55.656629, 55.652122, 55.647353), ncol=2)
p1a <- Polygon(coords1a)
p1a <- Polygons(list(p1a), ID = "p1a")
myPolys1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(p1a))
spdf2 = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(myPolys1, data.frame(variable1 = c(2),
                                                      variable2 = c(3), row.names = c("p1a")))
proj4string(spdf2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84
+towgs84=0,0,0")
plot(spdf2, col="yellow", add=T)
```

[image]

I want to cut out parts of `spdf1` that are intersected by `spdf2`. However, I want `spdf1` to remain as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and to retain any information contained within `spdf1@data`.

I¹ve tried gDifference as follows, which cuts out parts of `spdf1` that are
intersected by `spdf2`, but then converts `spdf1` to SpatialPolygons (i.e. discarding information contained in `spdf1@data`).

```
gDifference(spdf1, spdf2, byid=T)
```

How can I cut into `spdf1` with `spdf2` but retain data contained in `spdf1@data`? I have checked and tried this similar question without [how to overlay a polygon over SpatialPointsDataFrame and preserving the SPDF data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63793/how-to-overlay-a-polygon-over-spatialpointsdataframe-and-preserving-the-spdf-dat)

Answer (score 10):

The simplest approach would be

```
  library(raster)
  x <- spdf1 - spdf2

  # or, more formally
  y <- erase(spdf1,  spdf2)
```

See ?'raster-package' (section XIV) for more functions that deal with polygon overlay. These functions use the base-functions of rgeos under the hood, in 'user-level' (as opposed to 'developer-level') functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "in 'user-level' (as opposed to 'developer-level') functions"?

Comment: `rgeos` provides geometric operations but does not deal with the attributes of the data. Thus using these functions requires a lot of work to keep everything together. The raster functions simplify this and the behave like similar functions in GIS software,

Comment: Yeah, but this can lead to Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(part2, x@data[match(row.names(part2),  : 
  row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match

Comment: That would be a bug. Can you provide an example of that?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround would be to re-add the attributes after doing the clip, while converting from `SpatialPolygons` to `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

```
sp3 <- gDifference(spdf1, spdf2, byid = TRUE)
row.names(sp3) <- row.names(spdf1)

spdf3 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp3, data = spdf1@data)

spdf3@data

   variable1 variable2
p1       232       235
p2       242       464

plot(spdf3, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a problem I have, only the output clip in my particular instance produces rownames from spdf1 that do not exist (as a simple gsub to get rid of the 2nd digit in row.names should take care of the rownames match, no?)

Comment: Error in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(clip, data = as.data.frame(all_spdfs_together@data)) : 
  Object length mismatch:
     clip has 1718 Polygons objects, but as.data.frame(all_spdfs_together@data) has 86 rows

Comment: Sure - I have a bunch of polygons of things in the ocean. Some are incorrectly placed on land, or overlap with land. I want to clip that out so I only have areas that are in the ocean. I have a coastline shapefile to compare against. Here's the code - https://gist.github.com/jebyrnes/c2e8d2b6c82849dad3a813d952ab8bb0

Comment: nevermind - the raster::erase solution works (it hadn't before for some odd reason)