# clipping two SpatialPolygons : Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc

Tags: polygon, r, clip

I want to clip two SpatialPolygons on R without success, I followed the article in the disscution [How to perform a true GIS clip of polygons layer using a polygon layer in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93096/how-to-perform-a-true-gis-clip-of-polygons-layer-using-a-polygon-layer-in-r)

Polygone 01 :

```
> polygone1
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 1 
extent      : -8.673868, 11.98891, 19.43771, 37.09514  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Polygone 02 :

```
> Polygone2
class       : SpatialPolygons 
features    : 4 
extent      : 0.665381, 12.35598, 30.72105, 37.50386  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Code :

```
clip2 <- gIntersection(Polygone1, Polygone2, byid=TRUE)
```

Erreur :

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_not_poly, "rgeos_intersection") : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 8.1451386683704339 37.192197131616837 at 8.1451386683704339 37.192197131616837
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you intend to use Polygone1 for both arguments? What's the point of that?

Comment: I edited my post, it was a mistake clip2 <- gIntersection(Polygone1, Polygone2, byid=TRUE)

Comment: The error seems to say it all. The first polygon has a self-intersection and the command doesn't support that. You can check if a polygon is valid with gIsValid command. http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rgeos/docs/RGEOSisValid

Comment: thanks Rich ,how to correct it?

Comment: I have ArcGIS so I would fix it there. I don't know if it can be done within R. Might be best to ask a new question and describe what file format you have and the software you have available. Search this site first, there might be an answer already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
polygone1 <- gBuffer(polygone1, byid=TRUE, width=0)
polygone2 <- gBuffer(polygone2, byid=TRUE, width=0)
clip2 <- gIntersection(Polygone1, Polygone2, byid=TRUE)
```

It is ugly, but it usually solves this kind of problem.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

What we need is intersect function, not the gIntersection function. gIntersecion function provides a logical array, but intersect provides the actual intersect polygons.