# True GIS clip of polygons + attribute table

Tags: r, clip, intersection, intersect

How can a true intersection/clipping of polygons be done in R?

Problem description:
Shapefile1 contains only one feautre without attributes (or - at least - attibutes don't matter).
Shapefile2 contains several features, some of them fall entirely, some of the partly in the feature contained in Shapefile1. Other features fall totally outside.

I need to perform a true clip or intersection (just like in QGIS Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect). So far, the solution is described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93096/how-to-perform-a-true-gis-clip-of-polygons-layer-using-a-polygon-layer-in-r/107773#107773). However, in addition to the cited I also DO need the clip to inherit attributes of Shapefile2.

At the end, the result needs to be exported to an ESRI Shapefile.

Any answer, suggestion is welcome!

Comment: why not simply use QGis?

Comment: It would be easier, but I need the process to automated...

Comment: You should supply sample data, and draw a diagram to explain your process better.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368054/keeping-metadata-when-using-gintersection-from-rgeos-package-in-r) thread.

```
clipped_geom <- gIntersection(shp1, shp2, byid = TRUE, drop_lower_td = T) #clip polygon2 with polygon1
id_list <- sapply(clipped_geom@polygons, function(x) x@ID)
intersect_list <- gIntersects(shp1, shp2, byid = TRUE)
clipped_data <-  at@data[intersect_list,]
row.names(clipped_data ) <- id_list
clipped <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(clipped_geom,clipped_data )

writeOGR(clipped,mypath,"myfile","ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Here the handicap of stackoverflow.com and stackexchange.com being separate sites comes out: the answer has been present on stackoverflow for >2 years. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15075361/how-to-perform-a-vector-overlay-of-two-spatialpolygonsdataframe-objects