# R problem: Crop Spatialpolygon with another Spatial object returns a square. Why?

Tags: r, polygon, clip, rstudio

I am using the raster::crop function to cut a Shape of multiple polygons (Agricultural Plots Information System) with another polygon (Formal Class spatialPolygonDataframe) and instead of cutting the shape of the MCP (single polygon) return a the first shape in a Square.

Any idea?

The code is:

```
maps <- c(map21, map22) #multipoligons I want to cut
mcpid2 <- crop(maps[[1]], mcpid)
```

I get this:

[image]

and I want this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is what raster::crop does:

```
Description:

     crop returns a geographic subset of an object as specified by an
     Extent object (or object from which an extent object can be
     extracted/created).  If ‘x’ is a Raster* object, the Extent is
     aligned to ‘x’. Areas included in ‘y’ but outside the extent of
     ‘x’ are ignored (see ‘extend’ if you want a larger area).
```

Hard to be definitive with what you really need without fuller details, but it sounds like you have `sp` polygons which means you need functions from the `rgeos` package to do geometric operations like intersections. Alternatively use the `sf` package and its functions (eg `st_intersection`) to chop polygons with polygons.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with

```
raster::intersect(maps[[1]], mcpid)
```

Thank you.

This helped: [How to perform a true GIS clip of polygons layer using a polygon layer in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93096/how-to-perform-a-true-gis-clip-of-polygons-layer-using-a-polygon-layer-in-r)

Comment: you can accept your own answer as solving the question. This will help others having the same question and it will not show up in the un-answered questions log.