# Cutting leaflet map in R to a specific area

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet-r

I am trying to cut a leaflet map in R, so I only show a specific municipality. I have manage to hide the remaining municipalities in the country, but that leaves the water and the rest of the world visible.

```
dk <- getData("GADM",country="Denmark",level=2)

frb <- dk[dk$ID_2!=10,]

leaflet() %>%
  setView(lat=55.680544, lng=12.519379,zoom=13)%>%
  addTiles(group="Kort") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = frb,
          fillColor= "white",
          fillOpacity = 1, 
          weight = 2, 
          color = "white")
```

I think I need to make a polygon of the remaining world and make it white, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Would it be easier to use `setMaxBounds` to stop people scrolling outside your area of interest?

Comment: @Spacedman : Yes, that would indeed be a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would possibly proceed as follows:

- first, create a worldwide raster using the default spatial extent of the 'missing' method (see `?raster`: xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90);
- then, transform this template into a 'Spatial*' object using `rasterToPolygons`;
- and finally, cut a hole into it using `gDifference` from **rgeos** (inspired by [Remove intersect of one polygon from another in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52817/remove-intersect-of-one-polygon-from-another-in-r)).

Here is the resulting code. Interactive data display is realized through **mapview**. Make sure to have a look at `mapviewGetOption("basemaps")` which lists the single map types compatible with `mapview()`'s 'map.type' argument.

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(mapview)

## select municipality
dk <- getData("GADM", country = "Denmark", level = 2)
mc <- dk[10, ]

## create mask using worldwide raster as template
wld <- rasterToPolygons(raster(ncol = 1, nrow = 1, crs = proj4string(mc)))
msk <- gDifference(wld, mc)

## setup map and zoom to municipality
m <- mapview(msk, color = "white", alpha = 1, alpha.regions = 1) + mc
m
```

[image: map]